# Where is Eluned in the final stages of Song of the Elves?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I'm at the final boss battle of Song of the Elves, but my teleport crystal is out of charges. I looked for Eluned in Lletya, where she has been throughout the quest, but she's not here. I tried looking in the Underground Pass where I saw her last during the quest but she isn't there either. Where can I find Eluned during the very last part of Song of the Elves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eluned can probably not be found at all at the current stage in the quest, but there is an Elven Scout located in Eluned's normal spot prior to Song of the Elves who can enchant your crystal instead. Exit Lletya, head south to the Magic trees, and hop worlds until you find her. Then, you can enchant your crystal for the normal cost through dialog.

[image: The location of the Elven Scout]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but I found this thread today hoping to find Eluned, not for teleport crystal recharging, which has already been covered by a different answer, but rather for a hard clue step.

If that's the case, the Elven Scout won't work and you have to talk to Eluned specifically. She *can* still be found, but not in or around Lletya. Instead, you'll have to make your way through the Underground Pass to the dwarven encampment area. If you're coming from the elven entrance of Underground Pass, you may have to keep going back and forth across the agility platforms until you fall, as the normal means of getting down is a crevice, which during this part of the quest, sends you to the boss fight instead of the lower floor.

Once you're down, head to the northeast part of the giant room, and there you'll find the elven forces amassing, including Eluned who will help you with your clue.